Where is the Cf capacitor in this design for the LM2597SX-5.0?
I used the WEBENCH power designer tool from TI for the LM2596SX-5.0 buck converter(Vin min = 11V, Vin max = 13V, Vout = 5V, Iout max = 3A). The problem is I have a Cf capacitor in the bill of materials, but it is nowhere placed on the schematic. From what I have seen the LM2596S-ADJ sometimes requires a Cff CAP across R2, but in my case I have a fixed output LM2596 and I also have no R2 on the schematic. If it's not a mistake, than where should I place the Cf CAP? Any insight is helpful!
UPDATE: I posted the question on TI's forum as well and I got my response, I will leave a screenshot down below.


Response from the TI forum:


How does this differ from your previous question on the same topic?

@TimWilliams it doesn't, last time I asked the question I didn't get a definitive answer so I tried one more time. If it's a problem I can delete the question.

Have you contacted TI about it? This isn't exactly something we can answer short of "I guess that's how WEBENCH works"; their forums, or support, are a more appropriate venue than here.

@TimWilliams I asked the question on the TI forum as well, but I haven't got a response yet.

Looks to be an error in Webbench. There is no ‘Cf’ in the datasheet, only feedforward capacitor Cff.
And you don’t need that for the fixed voltage version.
Maybe you can inform TI.

The LM2596SX-5.0 datasheet contains the following description for the Feedforward Capacitor (CFF) :

I.e. CFF is described as only being required for the LM2596-ADJ adjustable output voltage version.
Perhaps it is a "bug" in the TI WEBENCH that a Cf capacitor is listed in the bill of materials for the a design which uses the LM2596SX-5.0 fixed 5.0 V output voltage.
I'm not a user of the TI WEBBENCH, but it looks like this question has been also asked on the TI forums in LM2596: Where is the Cf capacitor in this design for the LM2597SX-5.0?
Where is the Cf cap in this design? is a similar question.

I asked the question on the TI forum as well, but usually I like to get more opinions so this time I asked on both sites. I know there is a similar question "Where is the Cf cap in this design?", it was asked by me :). Thank you for the help!
